# I can't use SSV with expo-ads-admob

Tags: react-native, admob, expo, rewardedvideoad, admob-rewardedvideoad

#### I can't use ServerSideVerifications for Expo Admob

I am using expo-ads-admob in my app. I set my ad for server side verification but I can't set user_id or custom data for ad in my app.

`await AdMobRewarded.requestAdAsync({ servePersonalizedAds: true, additionalRequestParams: {user_id:122}});`

I am getting transaction_id in my server but I can't receive user_id.

Also I tried to get transaction_id for ad in my app but I can't get it too.
How can I use ServerSideVerification for admob with expo?

Thanks.

Comment: Same behavior for me i am completely stuck... @Expo team need to do something about this